# Howto implement UISearchDisplayController in a UIViewController without Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a `UIViewController` which has a grouped `UITableView` as a property. I instantiate the `UITableView` in code and don't use IB. I would like to hook up a `UISearchDisplayController` to it but can't find any example how this could be done.

This what I have.
     //Have implemented the UISearchDisplayDelegate in the header file

```
//SearchBar
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 45)];
searchBar.barStyle=UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
searchBar.showsCancelButton=NO;
searchBar.autocorrectionType=UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
searchBar.autocapitalizationType=UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
searchBar.delegate=self;


UISearchDisplayController *mySearchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc ]initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
self.searchDisplayController = mySearchDisplayController;  //Error here ?? self.searchDisplayController is ReadOnly and can't assign

[self.searchDisplayController setDelegate:self];
[self.searchDisplayController setSearchResultsDataSource:self];

[mySearchDisplayController release];
[myDisplayController release];
```

This doesn't seem to work, the searchDisplayController propery of the `UIViewController` seems to be readonly and I can't hook `myDisplayController` onto it. I'm really not sure if this the right way to do it.

I've been looking all around google to find some tip or tutorial on how to use a `UISearchDisplayController` in `UIViewController`. All the examples I could find was how to implement it into `UITableViewController` using IB, which is not the way I want to use it.

Can anyone explain how I could get this working ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's the code that I use.  Put this in viewDidLoad of a UIViewController that instantiates it's own UITableView.  I think the part you're looking for is to add the search bar as the header view of the table view.

```
UISearchBar * theSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,40)]; // frame has no effect.
theSearchBar.delegate = self;
if ( !searchBarPlaceHolder ) {
    searchBarPlaceHolder = @"What are you looking for?";
}
theSearchBar.placeholder = searchBarPlaceHolder;
theSearchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;


self.theTableView.tableHeaderView = theSearchBar;

UISearchDisplayController *searchCon = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc]
                                        initWithSearchBar:theSearchBar
                                        contentsController:self ];
self.searchController = searchCon;
[searchCon release];
searchController.delegate = self;
searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;

[searchController setActive:YES animated:YES];
[theSearchBar becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: It's an instance of UISearchDisplayController

Comment: @luyuan: I think `searchController` is `UISearchDisplayController` object and @Rayfleck forgot talk about it. You can create 1 `UISearchDisplayController` object like `UISearchDisplayController` of `UIViewController`. It will work same as `UIViewController`

Comment: What is searchBarPlaceHolder ?

Comment: Oh, I think its just an NSString.

Answer (score 5):

See the Apple Docs:

> ```
> @property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UISearchDisplayController *searchDisplayController
> ```
>
> Discussion: This property reflects the value of the
>   searchDisplayController outlet that you set in Interface Builder. If
>   you create your search display controller programmatically, this
>   property is **set automatically by the search display controller when
>   it is initialized**.

Comment: I don't understand, "If you create your search display controller programmatically," what does this mean?